# Как поставить переменную из index.html в главный код, React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Сделал приложение с погодой, сейчас его меняю, дополняю, есть код, хочу использовать ymaps api но не знаю как его импортировать, в index.html он есть в скрипте,

```
console.log(geolocation.city)
```

выводит мой город, но надо подставить на переменную city этот geolocation.city, но в App.js(основной код), как это сделать?
Вот код который в App.js:

```
state = {
  city: undefined,
  temp: undefined,
  weather: undefined,
  speed: undefined,
  deg: undefined,
  pressure: undefined,
  humidity: undefined,
  error: undefined
}
```

скрипт в index.html:

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
  var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation;
  if (geolocation) {
    $(function($){
      var city = geolocation.city
      console.log(city);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Не удалось установить местоположение');
  }
}
```

Надо вставить переменную city в App.js, или как-нибудь импортировать Yandex Maps в index.js

Comment: чет мало кода, в `App.js` только стейт? Как с ним компонент работает?

Comment: самый быстрый вариант, создать глобальную переменную в скрипте в index.html
window.ymapsCity = geolocation.city;
в App.js можете использовать window.ymapsCity

Comment: ThisMan, кода много, я просто скинул именно то место где надо поставить переменную

Comment: Nickolay Rudak, Спасибо все работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Nickolay Rudak за ответ, но в комментариях так что цитирую:

> ***самый быстрый вариант, создать глобальную переменную в скрипте в index.html window.ymapsCity = geolocation.city; в App.js можете использовать window.ymapsCity***